# How to log in using the TTY?

Tags: login

I'm getting the following error and I read a solution in another post but I'm having trouble with the first step which is logging into my credentials:

`Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.`

It's embarrassing but it reads `myusername login:`

[image]

So like when I boot up normally I enter in my password but then it asks for a password. So if my normal password goes in the latter what do I enter in the first part?

I hope I'm not making myself look like an idiot here. I also apologize in advance if I'm not following the correct posting rules but I'm on a new cell phone with no access to another comp.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? The question isn't clear enough which login you are talking about. You can take a screenshot using the PrintScreen button on your keyboard.

Comment: I'm unable to log in to my comp but I did take a pic with my phone but now I don't see an attach button...

Comment: Upload the image to imgur.com and paste the link to your question.

Comment: Wow fast reply okay I need to  one sec

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/77m1d451l54ujxg/2014-04-07%2018.08.15.jpg

Comment: So seventen is,my login name but it is asking for another login?

Comment: You need to enter "sevenTen" ahead of "Seventen login: ". Remember linux is case sensitive, so you need to enter the correct login name with the correct case for both the login id/name and password.

Comment: When I try to enter seventen ahead. It overwrites the seventen of "seventeen login:"   hope this makes sense

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed responses and for your time.

Answer (score 9):

No, it doesn't read "myusername login:". It reads "mycomputername login:"

You've simply used your username as your computer name. In the "login" field, you're supposed to enter a username and then enter the password for that user in the "password" field.

So on my desktop, it would read

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS HomeDesktop tty1

HomeDesktop login: jes
Password: ********************
```

Comment: Ooo okay that makes sense. But I've always just entered my password under my computer name at the login screen when it boots normally. Now I don't know what to put after login:   thx for your patience btw

Comment: Sorry jobin. I don't know what to put after login. SevenTen is the account I login to when it boots up normally. Is it something that I set up before?

Comment: SevenTen is also your _computers_ name. For instance, if you joined the example.com domain, the address to your computer would be seventen.example.com. So you put your username in the login field so that it says "SevenTen login: seventen". (Hopefully your username is lowercase)

Comment: I am certain the account I login to is SevenTen and of my password as well but it's not accepting it.

Comment: Remember that you have to enter it precisely how it's written. If it's "seventen", you cannot enter "SevenTen".

Comment: Yes..I'm sure of it but :( Thank you though! I learned a lot. I'll do some thinking. Appreciate it. Take care

Comment: You can log into recovery mode and reset your password if you want to. From there you can also create a new user if you need to. In other words, this is no disaster at all.

Comment: Thanks Jobin, really. I just moved to Australia and I'm trying to find work, and then my computer decides to do this, sigh. I tried going to recovery mode by holding the shift button down in the beginning, but nothing came up. I think it's because I switched out the screen and it's not the original model anymore. I'm sort of stuck...any pointers =\

Answer (score 1):

Use the number keys placed above the letter keys instead of the num-pad.  That's why your password is getting messed up.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

For those who have access to the graphical environment and just want to know their login in a simple way, that worked for me:

I opened my terminal and I typed `sudo su` to enter on root mode. The option to enter my password appears, and there it is! My prompt shows `[sudo] password for thiago:`, so "thiago" is my log in!

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you wxpwct OP to opeb a terminal when his graphic environt  aren't detected and he get a console login instead of GUI ? Anyway I hope he found a solution back in2014 ;-)

Comment: I answered this because I had to use TTY for a certain procedure and the only reference I found on the net was this post, but I had difficulty logging in. I put to help others who may have gone through the same problem as me : /