# I have deleted XFCE, exo and Terminal in Xubuntu, how to get them back?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, software-center, xfce, webbrowser-app

First, a piece of advice: in Xubuntu 18.04, there is a pre-installed application called Web Browser. It is ***NOT*** a Web Browser. I uninstalled it via Software Center thinking it was redundant with Firefox around, but it deleted a bunch of things, among them exo something (no idea what those are but they look important), File Manager, Terminal and who knows what else.

This is exactly what happened to me:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1216218

> When I looked to my installed apps in GNOME Software, I saw a "Web
>   browser" with very little info, so I removed it. GNOME Software issued
>   no warning and I removed exo and half of Xfce (I was running on Xfce).
>   After restart, everything stopped working (no xfdesktop, na panel,
>   etc...).
>
> I consider this dangerous.

Now, desktop is gone, with Super key + R I get the list of installed apps, most of them are still there and launching. Opened Software Center, but when I try to re-install Web Browser, Terminal or File Manager, I have an error mentioning unset dependencies.

My question is: how can I get back what I deleted with no Terminal? Of course no back-up, it is my father's PC, I am managing it for him (and not doing a very good job it seems).

Much appreciated. And for the love of God, ***DO NOT*** delete that ill-named Web Browser app.

**UPDATE FROM 18/12/2018**

Guys, thank you but no luck. I managed to get to a terminal with `Crtl` + `Alt` + `Fwhatever` but I have the following screen:

[image]

`Macol` is the username used during installation, I tried with the password but I keep on getting `Login incorrect`. I do not even know what I should type after `Macol login`, the username is already there. The password is the right one (4 numbers), the keyboard has the right layout, I tried to type it in the previous field (the PC has no numpad, I used the row under F keys) and no problems. I also tried CAPS on/off for the username. `sudo` of course is not working.

My options now are:

1. Login with your help and try your previous suggestions
2. Format everything by installing Xubuntu 18.10 and call it a day

Comment: can you get to a command line with ctrl+alt+F3 ?

Comment: Can you access a terminal interface? (ctrl+alt+f4 or whatever fn key you prefer)  When it deletes  If it was me, I'd look at your logs, and just re-install what you removed; or at worst you could `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop`

Comment: The Web Browser shortcut you see opens what the default web browser is set to.  You can run a command from a terminal window like `exo-open www.google.com` that will launch your default web browser to Google.  From the `exo-open` man page:  `exo-open - Open URLs and launch preferred applications`  When in doubt, try looking in the man pages for what applications are used for.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/50624/231142 for the possibility of recovering accidentally removed apps from a terminal window like using `Ctrl+Alt+f3`

Comment: Thank you guys, I di not have daily access to my dad's PC, I will try all of the above when there and report back. I feel such an idiot, like I had deleted System32 back in the Windows days.

Comment: _“I do not even know what I should type after Macol login, the username is already there.”_ Not really. Your _hostname_ is there. The username might be the same (or the same in lowercase). See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/444289/how-to-log-in-using-the-tty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I switch between GUI and command line startup?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/960057/how-do-i-switch-between-gui-and-command-line-startup)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Xubuntu 14.04 desktop over ubuntu 14.04 desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/794112/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help guys, but I ended up re-installing everything, Xubuntu 18.10 this time.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to drop to a command shell with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

From there you can log in and run some fixit commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade --fix-missing
```

Then you can try to install/reinstall xubuntu-core/desktop

```
sudo apt install --reinstall xubuntu-core xubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: Thank you, will try that as soon as I am at my dad's. Will report back and mark it as resolved if so.